# Code executes before i press enter after input

Tags: java, user-input

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NltrD.png)

The following code to find max Number from N+1 size array excluding number N from it.
After I run code and copy paste sample input of 3 testcases.... some of the testcases answer are already shown as seen in the attached picture. Why does that happen and how to avoid it???

```
package beginner;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FindMax { 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        BufferedReader sc = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        
        int t = Integer.parseInt(sc.readLine());
        
        while(t>0) {
            
            String [] in = sc.readLine().split(" ");
            int [] arr = new int[in.length];
            
            for(int j=0; j<in.length; j++) {
                arr[j] = Integer.parseInt(in[j]);
            }
            System.out.println(findMax(arr));
            t--;
        }
    
    }

    private static int findMax(int[] arr) {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int n = arr.length-1;
        
        for(int j=0; j<arr.length; j++) {
            if(arr[j] == n) continue;
            
            if(max < arr[j]) max = arr[j];
        }
        
        return max;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the text you're pasting to the console contains newline characters, it triggers the `nextLine` to return, and the result of `findMax` is printed after that.

Comment: @Sreeraj Paste input line-by-line, or collect results in an array and print them after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code (It would print the min, max, avg , sum , omit the part you wont need) :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*; 

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        System.out.println("Enter how many numbers you want to enter : ");
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String str = br.readLine();
        int k = Integer.parseInt(str);
        int arr[] = new int[k];
        
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers : ");
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++) {
            BufferedReader br1= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            str=br1.readLine();
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(str);
        }
        
        findMax(arr);
    }
        
    private static void findMax(int[] arr) {
        int sum=0,i,count=0,max,min,n;
        int len = arr.length;            
        float avg;
        
        max = arr[0];
        min = arr[0];
        while(count < len) {
            sum += arr[count];
            if(min > arr[count])
                min = arr[count];
            if (max < arr[count])
                max = arr[count];
            count += 1;
        }
        
        avg = sum/len;
        
        System.out.println("\nPrinting the results : \n");
        System.out.println("Sum     = " +sum);
        System.out.println("Average = " +avg);
        System.out.println("Maximum = " +max);
        System.out.println("Minimum = " +min);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Enter how many numbers you want to enter :                                                                                                                   
3                                                                                                                                                            
Enter the numbers :                                                                                                                                          
1                                                                                                                                                            
2                                                                                                                                                            
3                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                             
Printing the results :                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                             
Sum     = 6                                                                                                                                                
Average = 2.0                                                                                                                                              
Maximum = 3                                                                                                                                                
Minimum = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but i was concerned about the code being executed before i press the ENTER  key....You can see the issue in the pic i have attached